# Is a Ritual Summon still considered a Tribute Summon?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I ask because I was summoning my [Blue Eyes Chaos MAX Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_Chaos_MAX_Dragon) with [Chaos Form](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos_Form). And it requires to either remove [Blue Eyes White Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon) from the game or to sacrifice monsters from my hand whose levels are greater than or equal to it's level. Now while it is a special summon, is it still a tribute summon since the ritual requires me to tribute monsters for it?

Comment: no it is not a tribute summon it is a ritual summon

Comment: @WhatsThePoint would you mind posting that answer as an answer and adding substantiation?

Comment: @doppelgreener i dont have time to create an asnwer at the moment, but basically along the lines as a tribute summon is still classed as a normal summon, but a ritual summon is classed as a special summon

Answer (score 5):

**A Ritual Summon is a type of Special Summon, and a Tribute Summon is a type of Normal Summon. These types of summoning are distinct, so ritual summoning Chaos Max will not count as a tribute summon.**

Yes, it's true that ritual summoning requires you to **tribute** monsters from your hand or field (or other places, depending on the card), but tributing these monsters is merely a cost for the special summon. Just because tributing is involved doesn't make it the same as normal summoning a level 5 or higher monster by tributing a monster(s) you control.

However, as an aside, it should be noted that in both the case of a ritual summon and a tribute summon, any effect of the tributed monster that triggers when it is tributed will still trigger (for example, [Evoltile Najasho](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Evoltile_Najasho)'s effect will trigger regardless of whether if it was tributed for a tribute summon, a ritual summon or even a card effect like [Big Evolution Pill](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Evolution_Pill)).